# cells not getting saved openpyxl python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Here is an is an example file i'm parsing through
[image]

```
pay = 10000
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
info = wb["info.xlsx"]


for i in files_to_parse:

        # opening the sheet
        i = wb[i]
        counter = 0
        # checking being on the track of roll number rows

        while isinstance(i["A"+str(4+counter)].value, int):

            # printing their attendance
            print(i["C"+str(4+counter)].value)
            # checking if the student is present

            if i["C"+str(4+counter)].value == "Present":

                money_cell = "C"+str(counter+5)
                # adding their pay data into info sheet
                info[money_cell].value = (info[money_cell].value)+pay
                #printing the value of newly updated cell
                print(money_cell+" = "+str(info[money_cell].value))
            counter += 1

# look i AM saving the file
wb.save(file)
```

Here is the output

```
Present
C5 = 10000
Present
C6 = 10000
Present
C7 = 10000
ABSENT
ABSENT
ABSENT
```

So after printing out the cell values it is clear that the loop code is working to update values
But it does not save those cells particularly
This is just a small part of my other code...other areas are getting saved except for this stuff
[image]
this is the info sheet after not saving those 0 cells

Answer (score 0):

oh i got it
just needed to create a dictionary
update all the values there and in the end use the dictionary to update the values in the cells
i know it does not make any sense...good job to the authors